# Java If statement not running inside the while loop

Tags: java

I am trying to parse a CSV file that has the **format**: **name, gender, popularity**.I want to count all the females present inside the file but I unable to do so. Here's a **sample data** from the file : **Mary, F, 51479**. Here's my code :

```
import java.io.*;

public class CSVFile {
    public static void main(String [] args)throws IOException{
        String file_name = "xyz.csv";

        BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file_name));

        String line ;

        int female_count = 0;

        while ((line = f.readLine()) != null){

            String [] values = line.split(",");

            if (values[1] == "F"){
                female_count += 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(female_count);

    }
}
```

Can someone please explain it to me that why is my "if" statement not running?
Thank You !!

Comment: You need to use ```equals``` method for string operation. ```==``` compares the address of both object and hence will always be false.

Comment: ```if (values[1].equals("F"))``` should be the valid code .

Comment: I really hate it when beginners complain that if-statements aren't working. So far, this has always been a case of String comparison not using String#equals(). Just ask yourself one question: are you more likely to make a mistake in your code, or for you to find a compiler bug?

Answer (score 3):

The following String `Mary, F, 51479`, when split by `,`, will return an array with items `Mary`,  `F`, and  `51479`. Notice that the leading spaces will make a `.equals()` comparison return false in your code.

In short, `.split()` will include a leading space in every item after the first in your example, so use `.trim()` to remove leading and tailing spaces. You are also not comparing Strings properly - use `.equals()`.

The following should work:

```
import java.io.*;

public class CSVFile {
    public static void main(String [] args)throws IOException{
        String file_name = "xyz.csv";

        BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file_name));

        String line ;

        int female_count = 0;

        while ((line = f.readLine()) != null){

            String [] values = line.split(",");

            if (values[1].trim().equals("F")){
                female_count += 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(female_count);

    }
}
```